# odbc connection error when transitioning django pyodbc application to apache

Tags: python, django, apache, pyodbc

I have tried the following fix:
https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=214

and am still getting the same error.

Any idea as to how I can remedy this situation?

here is a screenshot of the odbc dns listings[image]

Python code

```
import pyodbc
import datetime as dt
from broker.models import Customer, Usage, Invoice, Document


def import_customers(user_id,m_code):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=as400;PWD=*********;DBQ=PRODDTA')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    # the VNDRCODE of LQPPNATSLC is equivalent to the VENDORNUM of the LQPPNATVND !!!
    # the VNDRCODE of LQPPNATVND is ACTUALLY the decriptive name of the broker
    cursor.execute("""select b.CUSTNBR,
                             b.CONAME,
                             b.LASTNAME,
                             b.FIRSTNAME,
                             b.MIDDLEINT,
                             b.STREET1,
                             b.STREET2,
                             b.CITY,
                             b.STATE,
                             b.ZIPCODE,
                             b.ZIPEXTN,
                             b.PHONENBR,
                             a.PCID,
                             c.VNDRCODE as VNAME,
                             d.STREET1,
                             d.CITY,
                             d.STATE,
                             d.ZIPCODE,
                             a.VNDRCODE 
                    from LQPPNATSLC a, LQPPCUSMST b, LQPPNATVND c, LQPPDELDIR d
                    where a.CUSTNBR = b.CUSTNBR and
                          a.CUSTNBR = d.CUSTNBR and
                          a.VNDRCODE = c.VENDORNUM and
                          b.CUSTSTAT in ( '','RE') and
                          a.VNDRCODE = ? 
                    order by b.CUSTNBR """,str(m_code))

    Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).delete()
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:      
        b = Customer( user_id = user_id,
                    customer_number = row.CUSTNBR,
                    company_name = row.CONAME,
                    last_name = row.LASTNAME,
                    first_name = row.FIRSTNAME,
                    middle_initial = row.MIDDLEINT,
                    street_address1 = row.STREET1,
                    street_address2 = row.STREET2,
                    city = row.CITY,
                    state = row.STATE,
                    zip = row.ZIPCODE,
                    zip_ext = row.ZIPEXTN,
                    phone = row.PHONENBR,                   
                    PCID = row.PCID,
                    broker_name = row.VNAME, # see note above
                    service_address1 = row.STREET1,
                    service_city = row.CITY,
                    service_state = row.STATE,
                    service_zip = row.ZIPCODE,
                    broker_code = row.VNDRCODE.strip()
                    )
        b.save()
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Error from apache errror.log

```
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 115, in get_response
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\contrib\\auth\\decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]   File "C:\\dev\\broker_portal\\broker\\views.py", line 57, in customer_list
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]     as400.import_customers(user_id,marketer_code)
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]   File "C:\\dev\\broker_portal\\broker\\as400.py", line 7, in import_customers
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error]     cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=as400;PWD=*********;DBQ=PRODDTA')
[Mon Aug 26 13:50:41 2013] [error] Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Django debug error

```
Error at /broker/5/3/
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://djangodev.shipley.com/broker/5/3/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value:    
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Exception Location: C:\dev\broker_portal\broker\as400.py in import_customers, line 7
Python Executable:  C:\Apache2\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\dev\\broker_portal',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Apache2',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Apache2\\bin']
Server time:    Mon, 26 Aug 2013 13:50:41 -0400
```

meta data

```
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
HTTP_COOKIE 
'csrftoken=ukCmTMgFUDtnSBvbOWYexafiTa4FPmmV; sessionid=qnh4u7n6mishbc4ka1oofxfd2fhtiraw'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'Apache/2.2.25 (Win64) mod_wsgi/3.5-BRANCH Python/2.7.5'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile    
'0'
mod_wsgi.handler_script 
''
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
PATH_INFO   
u'/broker/5/3/'
SystemRoot  
'C:\\Windows'
QUERY_STRING    
''
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://djangodev.shipley.com/accounts/login/'
SERVER_NAME 
'djangodev.shipley.com'
REMOTE_ADDR 
'10.1.6.182'
mod_wsgi.request_handler    
'wsgi-script'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
PATH_TRANSLATED 
'C:\\dev\\broker_portal\\broker_portal\\wsgi.py\\broker\\5\\3\\'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
mod_wsgi.version    
(3, 5)
mod_wsgi.input_chunked  
'0'
SERVER_ADDR 
'10.1.4.161'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'C:/Apache2/htdocs'
mod_wsgi.process_group  
''
COMSPEC 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe'
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
'C:/dev/broker_portal/broker_portal/wsgi.py'
SERVER_ADMIN    
'admin@example.com'
wsgi.input  
<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x00000000044BD9F0>
HTTP_HOST   
'djangodev.shipley.com'
mod_wsgi.callable_object    
'application'
wsgi.multithread    
True
PATHEXT 
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
REQUEST_URI 
'/broker/5/3/'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
WINDIR  
'C:\\Windows'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.errors 
<mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x00000000044924F0>
REMOTE_PORT 
'50753'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-US,en;q=0.8'
mod_wsgi.application_group  
'DjangoDev.shipley.com|'
mod_wsgi.script_reloading   
'1'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
CSRF_COOKIE 
u'ukCmTMgFUDtnSBvbOWYexafiTa4FPmmV'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip,deflate,sdch'
```

httpd.conf modifications

```
AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /dev/broker_portal/broker/css/$1

# Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /dev/broker_portal/broker/static/

<Directory  /dev/broker_portal/broker/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

#<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
#Order deny,allow
#Allow from all
#</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /dev/broker_portal/broker_portal/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /dev/broker_portal

<Directory /dev/broker_portal/broker_portal>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Comment: I do not understand how the linked issue is related to your problem. The error message is stating that the DSN named `as400` is not found. Is that DSN defined? If so, can you please update your question with the definition and advise of the type (e.g. system, user, file)?

Comment: It is defined and has been in use for the past three weeks using the django runserver on the same machine.  I am transferring the application to an Apache server in preparation for putting it in production.  I will post documentation of the  DSN and odbc settings shortly.

Comment: Try creating the DSN as a System DSN. The Apache user should be running as a "system" user rather than as you.

Comment: I am logged in as system administrator when I create these.  How would would I do it differently to make it a system user?  I am not seeing any options in the dialog that I would associate with that...

Comment: ok.Researched it and created systems versions of both dsn's and now it is all working!  Benny Hill, if you want to write it up I will mark yours as the correct answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up the DSN as a System DSN because the Apache user is a "system" user and will be looking at the System DSN's rather than the User DSN's.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to embed the connection string, instead of maintaining a DSN outside of your code. You'll need to work with the connection string syntax, but here's something to get started (I'm using a mix a string and keywords as defined in the [pyodbc.connect](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) docs):

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('system=<insert system name';dbq='PRODDTA',
                      driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
                      uid='<insert user name>', pwd='<insert password>')
```

I find this method makes the inevitable code migration easier.

Answer (score 0):

This connection string for pyodbc, work for me:

```
conexion_str = 'SYSTEM=%s;db2:DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DRIVER=%s;' % (self._SYSTEM, self._DSN, self._UID, self._PWD, self._DRIVER)
cnn = pyodbc.connect(conexion_str)
```